# how to access to credentials get client_secret in keycloak

Tags: java, angular, postman, keycloak

I'm encountering an issue in the Keycloak dashboard. I'm unable to locate the credentials required to access the client_secret code.
[check the immage(dash)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0901.png)
i use the 23 version of keycloak, i need the client_secret to get access to login page

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable two items for your client
Then you can get the `client_secret` from UI.

```
Client authentication
Authorization
```

##### Menu Location

Clients/[front-fidlease]/Capability config
To finish the configuration by Clicking <kbd>Save</kbd> button

[image]

##### Client Secret

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Can you accept my answer? if you click the up arrow on my answer, it will give me 15 points score.